# C# "Initializers runs from derived to base" is obvious with Unity but not otherwise

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, derived-class

I am not sure if this is a unity bug but can anyone help me explain why the below program in the third case prints 150?

```
void Main()
{
// Test 1
Derived d = new Derived();
d.Height.Dump(); //Prints 10

// Test 2
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(Derived)).Dump(); // Prints 10

// Test 3 
unityContainer.RegisterType<IPrintHeightService<Derived>, PrintHeightService<Derived>>();
var output = unityContainer.Resolve<IPrintHeightService<Derived>>();
output.Show(); //Prints 150
}


public interface IHasHeight
{
    Int32 Height {get; set;}
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Default : IHasHeight
{
    public Int32 Height {get; set;}

    public Default()
    {
        Height = 150;
    }
}

public class Derived : Default
{
    public new Int32 Height {get { return 10;}}
}


public interface IPrintHeightService<T> where T:IHasHeight, new() 
{
    void Show();
}

public class PrintHeightService<T> : IPrintHeightService<T> where T:IHasHeight, new()
{
    private IHasHeight objectWithHeight;
    public PrintHeightService(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        objectWithHeight = (T) unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(T));
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(objectWithHeight.Height); // Prints 150
    }
}
```

I suspect this is because of the intializers are run from derived to base as explained (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx) but why it is obvious with unity and not otherwise?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you declared Height as `new`. By declaring it as `new`, Derived doesn't override Height, it just hides it. That has nothing to do with the initializers.

Which means that the new implementation doesn't have anything to do with the virtual Property declared by the Interface, it just happens to have the same name, thus "hiding" it. By calling Height over `IHasHeight` (in the `Show()` method of `PrintHeightService` you access a field with that type), the property declared by the interface is called, which is implemented in `Default`. You will only get `Derived.Height`, if you call it via a reference of the type `Derived`.

You can see for yourself: Change the type of the variable `d` in example 1 to `Default` or `IHasHeight` and you'll see that you will get 150, too.

If you truly want to override the implementation of `Height` in `Derived`

- Declare `Height` as `virtual` in `Default` and then
- Declare `Height` as `override` in `Derived`
- And remove the `new` modifier.

Comment: I removed "new" keyword and it did't help, if you print typeof(T) in the PrintHeightService constructor you'd see it is infact Derived type

Comment: @RohitSharma By only removing the `new` keyword, you are still hiding the original property. You should also get a warning about this. See my edited answer for a way to truly override the property.

Comment: I think it makes sense what you say, but what baffles me is that why when i do unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(Derived)) it creates an object with Height 10, but when I do objectWithHeight = (T) unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(T)); where T is type "Derived", it creates with 150 as height?

Comment: @RohitSharma It doesn't have anything to do with the unity container. If you hide a method or property by using the new modifier, only the type of the variable you call it on decides which property to use. And in your printservice, the variable is of type IHasHeight. In your current code, only Default actually implements IHasHeight.Height.  
unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(Derived)) returns Derived, so Derived.Height is called. If you call objectWithHeight.Height, the compiler doesn't know that the object is of type Derived, so it looks for IHasHeight.Height, which is implemented by Default.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, guess I am back to basics :)